How to elegantly read/write a struct field as little endian float?
I've written some code that intercepts data packets and modifies them. 4 bytes in the data packets represent a float value, but in reverse byte order (little-endian). And that creates a lot of issues for me. Let me explain with a simplified piece of code:
#include <Arduino.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t start_seq[2];
    uint8_t body_size;
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t unknown;
    uint8_t entity_id;
    uint8_t reserved[3];
    float value;
    uint8_t end_seq[2];
} Packet;

void printRawPacket(const char* message, const uint8_t* packet, size_t length) {
    Serial.print(message);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Serial.printf("%02X ", packet[i]);
    }
    Serial.println();
}

// Packet interceptor function
void handlePacket(uint8_t* raw_packet, size_t length) {
    // Create a pointer to the packet structure
    Packet* packet = (Packet*)raw_packet;

    printRawPacket("Original bytes: ", raw_packet, sizeof(raw_packet));
    // Correctly Prints: "Original bytes: BE EF 08 03 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 C0 40 EF BE"

    // Access the float value without creating a copy of the 4 bytes
    Serial.print("Original value: ");
    Serial.println(packet->value);
    // Incorrectly prints a random value or "ovf" instead of 6.00

    // Modify the float value without creating a copy of the 4 bytes
    packet->value = -120.0f; // little endian would be 00 00 F0 C2; big endian would be C2 F0 00 00
    Serial.print("Modified value: ");
    Serial.println(packet->value); // Prints -120.0 correctly

    printRawPacket("Modified bytes: ", raw_packet, sizeof(raw_packet));
    // Incorrectly Prints: "Modified bytes: BE EF 08 03 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 F0"
    // Showing the float value was not stored correctly and the footer was overwritten
    // Expected output would have been: "Modified bytes: BE EF 08 03 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 C2 EF BE"
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // Example packet
    uint8_t raw_packet[] = {
        // ------ HEADER ------
        0xBE, 0xEF, // start sequence
        0x08,       // body size uint8_t
        0x03,       // type uint8_t
        0x00,       // unknown
        // ------ HEADER ------

        // ------ BODY ------
        0x09,                   // entity id uint8_t
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // reserved
        0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x40, // value (float, little-endian) // 6.0f
        // ------ BODY ------

        // ------ FOOTER ------
        0xEF, 0xBE // end sequence
        // ------ FOOTER ------
    };

   handlePacket(raw_packet, sizeof(raw_packet));
}

void loop() {
    // Nothing to do here
}

As explained in the comments, this doesn't work on multiple levels.
I can easily work around that issue by making the value field a uint8_t value[4] and then using a getter and setter function like this:
typedef struct {
    uint8_t start_seq[2];
    uint8_t body_size;
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t unknown;
    uint8_t entity_id;
    uint8_t reserved[3];
    uint8_t value[4];
    uint8_t end_seq[2];

    // Function to get the float value from the raw packet in little-endian format
    float getFloatLeValue() const {
        // reverse byte order and return as float
        uint32_t temp = (value[3] << 24) | (value[2] << 16) | (value[1] << 8) | value[0];
        float result;
        memcpy(&result, &temp, sizeof(result)); // Copy uint32_t to float
        return result;
    }

    // Function to set the float value into the raw packet in little-endian format
    void setFloatLeValue(float newValue) {
        // Copy float to uint32_t
        uint32_t temp;
        memcpy(&temp, &newValue, sizeof(temp));
        // Copy uint32_t to value in little-endian format
        value[0] = temp & 0xFF;
        value[1] = (temp >> 8) & 0xFF;
        value[2] = (temp >> 16) & 0xFF;
        value[3] = (temp >> 24) & 0xFF;
    }
} Packet;

But this just seems so unnecessarily complex and complicated when all I wanna do is interpret 4 bytes in reverse.
Is there a simpler more elegant way?
(I'm writing my code in C++ on PlatformIO for an ESP32 using the Arduino Framework.)

"But this just seems so unnecessarily complex and complicated when all I wanna do is interpret 4 bytes in reverse." how is any of your code unnecessary? Looks pretty much like the minimum necessary code to me. There's std::bit_cast, but last I checked, arduino doesn't have C++20.

You would have same "issue" with any multi-byte types (as int16_t)... there are hton function family for integral types.

It may not technically be overly complicated if the architecture required float to always be big-endian, but I dislike the fact that I have to deal with code that translates between these formats. It would be nice to have some sort of syntax sugar like float_le value; in the struct, packet->value = (float_le)6.0f to set a value and float value = *(float *)packet->value to read a value. Or something close to that.

something like a trivially copyable class (containing e.g. char[4]) with an appropriate conversion constructor/operator?

You could make a class float_le { /*...*/ }; that encapsulates this behavior.

How would this be possible?

Maybe you need to explain what you are trying to accomplish and what is your use case, Arduino (and all modern CPU/MCU except go back to 68000) are little-endian machine, so you don't need to do anything for storing and retrieving a float, data are always stored in little-endian, there is no conversion need unless you need it for big endian (e.g. many data communication protocol send data in big endian).

Let's see how this would look with bit_cast suggested by @PasserBy. We can take an example implementation using memcpy from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast
Also let's use htonl/ntohl for the actual swap. Alternatively there is bswap_32.
template<class To, class From>
To my_bit_cast(const From& src) noexcept
{
  To dst;
  memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(To));
  return dst;
}

float getFloatLeValue() const {
    return my_bit_cast<float, uint32_t>(
        ntohl(
            my_bit_cast<uint32_t, uint8_t[4]>(value)));
}

void setFloatLeValue(float newValue) {
    uint32_t temp = htonl(my_bit_cast<uint32_t, float>(newValue));
    memcpy(&value, &temp, sizeof(value));
}

It's uh... Not that great?

About the float_le wrapper, the suggestion is:
class float_le {
    uint8_t value[4];
    public:
    float_le(float v) {
        // same as setFloatLeValue
    }
    operator float() const {
        // same as getFloatLeValue
    }
}

This is trivially copyable (e.g by memcpy) and is assignable/castable to/from ordinary float. Use inside the Packet struct as float_le value;. Could be useful if you need the flipped float in multiple places.
May have nasty alignment/padding issues. Let's see what comments point out.
